# Failed connecting to smtp port PHP

Tags: php, smtp

I'm always having this error whenever I try to send an email verification

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\register\MailSend.php on line 43

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, are you running a mail server on port 25? On Windows, unless you have deliberately installed one yourself, the answer is almost certainly no.

Comment: How do I change my port ? Can't find it on my php.ini file in xampp

Comment: And how do i know if I'm running on port 25?

Comment: well, as the error message indicates, you would set the value of `smtp_port`. But that’s not going to help you if you don’t have a mail server running.

Comment: Remember the `mail()` function does not actually send email. It just passes it to a real Mail Server.

Comment: @LanceEbacuado the first question is whether you’re running a mail server *at all*. If you are, then you can worry about the port (which is overwhelmingly likely to be 25). If you aren’t, all of this is moot. You almost certainly aren’t, based on this error and your questions.

Comment: Are you running on WINDOWS?

Comment: Yup running on windows 10

Comment: Then unless you installed an Email Server you dont have one! Take a look at a PHP based library called `phpMailer`. that will allow you to use a Gmail/Yahoo/etc emailaccount to send email. Alternatively if you think you have the skills or time,look for `hMailServer` its a windows mail server

Comment: Hey @riggsFolly Do you have any private account where I can message you to discuss about my problem ? Thanks

Comment: That Dup Should give you some clues

Comment: Someone said that i need to have a web hosting service before I can send an email to a user, is that really needed?